# Class using std::vector allocation slower than pointer allocation by a LOT

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, benchmarking

I have a class for handling allocation of arrays. My class is simple and it is defined as follows:

**DimArray.hpp:**

```
#ifndef DIMARRAY_HPP_INCLUDED
#define DIMARRAY_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class DimArray
{
    private:
        int Width, Height;
        std::vector<T> Data;

    public:
        DimArray(int Width, int Height);
        DimArray(T* Data, int Width, int Height);
        DimArray(T** Data, int Width, int Height);

        DimArray(const DimArray &da);
        DimArray(DimArray &&da);

        inline int size() {return Width * Height;}
        inline int size() const {return Width * Height;}

        inline int width() {return Width;}
        inline int width() const {return Width;}

        inline int height() {return Height;}
        inline int height() const {return Height;}

        inline T* operator [](int Index) {return const_cast<T*>(Data.data()) + Height * Index;}
        inline const T* operator [](int Index) const {return Data.data() + Height * Index;}

        DimArray& operator = (DimArray da);
};

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>::DimArray(int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {}

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>::DimArray(T* Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {std::copy(Data, Data + Width * Height, const_cast<T*>(this->Data.data()));}

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>::DimArray(T** Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {std::copy(Data[0], Data[0] + Width * Height, const_cast<T*>(this->Data.data()));}

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>::DimArray(const DimArray &da) : Width(da.Width), Height(da.Height), Data(da.Data) {}

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>::DimArray(DimArray &&da) : Width(std::move(da.Width)), Height(std::move(da.Height)), Data(std::move(da.Data)) {}

template<typename T>
DimArray<T>& DimArray<T>::operator = (DimArray<T> da)
{
    this->Width = da.Width;
    this->Height = da.Height;
    this->Data.swap(da.Data);
    return *this;
}

#endif // DIMARRAY_HPP_INCLUDED
```

For benchmark timing, I use the following:

**Timer.hpp:**

```
#ifndef TIME_HPP_INCLUDED
#define TIME_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <chrono>

#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
#include <windows.h>

template<typename T>
class Timer
{
    private:
        typedef T duration;
        typedef typename T::rep rep;
        typedef typename T::period period;
        typedef std::chrono::time_point<Timer, duration> time_point;
        std::chrono::time_point<Timer, duration> Time;
        static const bool is_steady = true;

        const rep g_Frequency = []() -> rep
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
            return frequency.QuadPart;
        }();

        inline std::chrono::time_point<Timer, duration> now()
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER count;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
            return time_point(duration(count.QuadPart * static_cast<rep>(period::den) / g_Frequency));
        }

    public:
        inline void Start() {this->Time = this->now();}
        inline rep End() {return std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(this->now() - this->Time).count();}
};
#else
template<typename T>
class Timer
{
    private:
        static const bool is_steady = true;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> Time;

    public:
        inline void Start() {this->Time = this->Clock.now();}
        inline T::rep End() {return std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(this->Clock.now() - this->Time).count();}
};
#endif

#endif // TIME_HPP_INCLUDED
```

And my benchmark is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Timer<std::chrono::nanoseconds> T;

    T.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        int** T2DArray = new int*[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            T2DArray[i] = new int[10000];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            delete[] T2DArray[i];
        }
        delete[] T2DArray;
    }
    std::cout<<T.End()<<" us\n\n";

    T.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        DimArray<int> TwoDArray(10000, 10000);
    }
    std::cout<<T.End()<<" us\n\n";
}
```

The results it printed were:

```
4.9599256 seconds  //for int**
42.9303941 seconds //for DimArray<int>
```

That's a huge difference! I cannot figure out why?!

So I changed it to:

```
int main()
{
    Timer<std::chrono::nanoseconds> T;

    T.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        int** T2DArray = new int*[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            T2DArray[i] = new int[10000];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            delete[] T2DArray[i];
        }
        delete[] T2DArray;
    }
    std::cout<<T.End()<<" us\n\n";

    T.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        int* TwoDArray = new int[10000 * 10000];
        delete[] TwoDArray;
    }
    std::cout<<T.End()<<" us\n\n";
}
```

and the results were:

```
4.6085725 seconds //for int**
0.1142958 seconds //for int*
```

Any ideas why my class that uses `std::vector` is so slow compared to using a raw pointer?

Comment: You ran it in the release mode, right?

Comment: Yes sir. Not in debug mode. G++ 4.8.1 on Windows 8.1, 2.5ghz processor, 8gb ram.

Comment: Note that we observed a similar effect [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20174822/420683), and partly attributed it to memory management. In fact, when I add a "strided memset" in your code that touches every memory page allocated by `new`, I get within 10% the same timings for all three approaches. Most notably, for `int**`, my simple RAM usage monitor shows next to no effect unless I add the "strided memset".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector` will zero out the memory it allocates for you. Your code with `new` gives you 
"garbage-init"'d memory. Thus, the allocation `TwoDArray(10000, 10000)` gives you an array full of zeros, while `new int[10000 * 10000]` gives you an array of undefined contents. (The mere *observation* of which causes undefined behavior)

Note that this means that in the vector case, your program actually writes to all `100000000` `int`s, while in the `new` case your program only sets aside address space for that many `int`s.

For comparable measurements you'd have to zero the new'd array out first; e.g. with `int* TwoDArray = new int[10000 * 10000]();` instead of `int* TwoDArray = new int[10000 * 10000];`.

Comment: Note that on most common platforms, it's OK to work with uninitialized data. So you can take advantage of working with it (as you possibly just benchmarked).

Comment: I see. Accepted. Is there a way to have the vector uninitialized memory?

Comment: @user2345215: Erm, no, it isn't. Observing it won't crash on most platforms, but you'll still read garbage results. (A valid form of "undefined behavior" is "appears to work") Of course, if your program initializes as it goes then there can be some win there. (You can use a custom allocator to disable the init there)

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: You could have e.g. `vector<int, YourAllocatorHere<int>>` where `YourAllocatorHere::construct` is a no-op.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: That said, in a real program, profile this. You're going to be memory bandwidth limited in this test; but real hardware will optimize away things like a store to a memory location followed by a store to the same memory location in many cases. Also, don't forget about `unique_ptr<int[]>` if you want to control allocation explicitly.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Sometimes it can be useful and defined to modify it (not overwrite). Consider a bit buffer class which modifies only what it has to (to write in the middle of it without problems).

Comment: @user: That would be undefined behavior -- observing an uninitialized value is allowed to be a trap representation, for example, which will terminate the program merely by reading the value. Though on most platforms it'll be okay.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes, that's what I meant. Game developers sometimes do this in their implementations of the standard library.

Comment: @user2345215 I see you're still having difficulty [understanding](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) [undefined](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/226) [behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/232). [Appearing to succeed is a valid form of undefined behavior, but it's still undefined](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/29/10217910.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: And you are failing to understand undefined behavior can be defined if you know what you are doing. Also, this is a different problem than our last argument.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate Billy ONeal's suggestion, and the dramatic results, I did this:

```
template <class T>
class no_init_alloc
    : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
    using std::allocator<T>::allocator;

    template <class U, class... Args> void construct(U*, Args&&...) {}
};

template<typename T>
class DimArray
{
    private:
        int Width, Height;
        std::vector<T, no_init_alloc<T>> Data;

    public:
        …
```

And my results changed from:

```
2959854464 us

28734347029 us
```

to:

```
2980402236 us

850190 us
```

Comment: Tried your allocator, still same speed for me. Nice code though. I'll play around with it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Hmm… My code is the same as your code except I added what is shown in my answer, and I had to add a `typename` in front of `T::rep` in `Timer`.  I even kept your misspelling of ns in the output. :-)  I suspect that if you're still getting the same speed that your implementation does not fully implement the `allocator_traits` spec with regards to calling the custom `construct` function (you could put a print statement in the custom `construct` to test that theory).  The compiler needs advanced (new in C++11) SFINAE capability for the std::lib to implement this.

Comment: I had to add: `template<typename U>
        struct rebind
        {
            typedef UninitialisedAllocator<T> other;
        };` to get it to work. Now it works just fine.

Comment: <nod>  My `no_init_alloc` is definitely a "thrown together" demonstration.  In real code I would recommend building an allocator from "scratch" instead of deriving from std::allocator.  But are you still getting no performance improvement?  Is your custom construct actually getting called?

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late from this New Year's Eve party.

---

Apart from providing a custom allocator, one can also call `reserve()` and then `push_back()` / `emplace_back()` when the actual data becomes available. It is also safe from the the point of view of undefined behavior: You can only access already initialized data. Unfortunately, this approach may not be suitable for your application.

---

One has to be very careful with this kind of benchmarking. For example, Linux does lazy allocation; if I run the code below, I get the followings:

> $ /usr/bin/time --verbose ./a.out
>   int[]:  0  ms
>   vector: 0  ms
>           ...
>           Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1004

If I uncomment any of the code in comment, it will become 391 MB.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

constexpr size_t SIZE = 100000000;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  {
    int* pInt = new int[SIZE];
    //int* pInt = new int[SIZE]();
    pInt[0] = 0;
    delete[] pInt;
  }

  auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();  

  {
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(SIZE);
    v.push_back(0);
    //v.resize(SIZE, 0);
  }

  auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  printf("int[]:  %ld  ms\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2-t1).count());
  printf("vector: %ld  ms\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3-t2).count());

}
```