# Overloaded vector operators causing a massive performance reduction?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am summing and multiplying vectors by a constant many many times so I overloaded the operators * and +.  However working with vectors greatly slowed down my program.  Working with a standard C-array improved the time by a factor of 40.  What would cause such a slow down?

An example program showing my overloaded operators and exhibiting the slow-down is below.  This program does k = k + (0.0001)*q, log(N) times (here N = 1000000).  At the end the program prints the times to do the operations using vectors and c-arrays, and also the ratio of the times.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
// -------- OVERLOADING VECTOR OPERATORS ---------------------------
vector<double> operator*(const double a,const vector<double> & vec)
{
  vector<double> result;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    result.push_back(a*vec[i]);
  return result;
 }

vector<double> operator+(const vector<double> & lhs,
         const vector<double> & rhs)
{
  vector<double> result;
  for(int i = 0; i < lhs.size();i++)
    result.push_back(lhs[i]+rhs[i]);
  return result;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------- Basic C-Array operations -------------------------
// s[k] = y[k];
void populate_array(int DIM, double *y, double *s){
  for(int k=0;k<DIM;k++)
    s[k] = y[k];
}
//sums the arrays y and s as y+c s and sends them to s;
void sum_array(int DIM, double *y, double *s, double c){
  for(int k=0;k<DIM;k++)
    s[k] = y[k] + c*s[k];
}
// sums the array y and s as a*y+c*s and sends them to s;
void sum_array2(int DIM, double *y, double *s,double a,double c){
  for(int k=0;k<DIM;k++)
    s[k] = a*y[k] + c*s[k];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(){
  vector<double> k = {1e-8,2e-8,3e-8,4e-8};
  vector<double> q = {1e-8,2e-8,3e-8,4e-8};
  double ka[4] = {1e-8,2e-8,3e-8,4e-8};
  double qa[4] = {1e-8,2e-8,3e-8,4e-8};
  int N = 3;
  clock_t begin,end;
  double elapsed_sec,elapsed_sec2;
  begin = clock();
  do
    {
      k = k + 0.0001*q;
      N = 2*N;
    }while(N<1000000);
  end = clock();
  elapsed_sec = double(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("vector time: %g \n",elapsed_sec);

  N = 3;
  begin = clock();
  do
    {
       sum_array2(4, qa, ka,0.0001,1.0);
       N = 2*N;
    }while(N<1000000);
  end = clock();
  elapsed_sec2 = double(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("array time: %g \n",elapsed_sec2);
  printf("time ratio : %g \n", elapsed_sec/elapsed_sec2);
}
```

I get the ratio of vector time to c-array timeto be typically ~40 on my linux system.  What is it about my overload operators that causes the slowdown compared to C-array operations?

Comment: What compiler flags did you use?

Comment: Lots of copying of vectors.

Comment: You are resizing the vectors; you are not resizing the arrays. Try a fair test.

Comment: debug or release build? You know the result size, so resize the vector, don't use push_back.

Comment: @GManNickG For this program called test.cc I just compiled using g++ -std=c++11 test.cc

nothing special.  Could adding compiler flags help?

Comment: Add `-O3` to your compile options.

Comment: If you don't test an optimized build, you're testing something not intended to run quickly. Turn optimizations on and try again.

Comment: [mcve].  The above code includes overloaded poorly written operators **which you then proceed to not use**.  Please include actual test code, eliminate irrelevant code, and include actual timing results and compiler flags.

Comment: Note that the standard library's `std::valarray<double>` already implements those overloaded operators.

Comment: According to cppreference.com, gcc and clang's versions of the standard library also implement expression templates for `std::valarray`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler , std::valarray worked great!  I knew there must have been something that implemented the operators I wanted.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
k = k + 0.0001*q;
```

To evaluate this, first the computer needs to call your `operator*`.  This function creates a `vector` and needs to allocate dynamic storage for its elements.  Actually, since you use `push_back` rather than setting the size ahead of time via constructor, `resize`, or `reserve`, it might allocate too few elements the first time and need to allocate again to grow the vector.

This created `vector` (or one move-constructed from it) is then used as a temporary object representing the subexpression `0.0001*q` within the whole statement.

Next the computer needs to call your `operator+`, passing `k` and that temporary `vector`.  This function also creates and returns a `vector`, doing at least one dynamic allocation and possibly more.  There's a second temporary `vector` for the subexpression `k + 0.0001*q`.

Finally, the computer calls an `operator=` belonging to `std::vector`.  Luckily, there's a move assignment overload, which (probably) just moves the allocated memory from the second temporary to `k` and deallocates the memory that was in `k`.

Now that the entire statement has been evaluated, the temporary objects are destroyed.  First the temporary for `k + 0.0001*q` is destroyed, but it no longer has any memory to clean up.  Then the temporary for `0.0001*q` is destroyed, and it does need to deallocate its memory.

Doing lots of allocating and deallocating of memory, even in small amounts, tends to be somewhat expensive.  (The vectors will use `std::allocator`, which is allowed to be smarter and avoid some allocations and deallocations, but I couldn't say without investigation how likely it would be to actually help here.)

On the other hand, your "C-style" implementation does no allocating or deallocating at all.  It does an "in-place" calculation, just modifying arrays passed in to store the values passed out.  If you had another C-style implementation with individual functions like `double* scalar_times_vec(double s, const double* v, unsigned int len);` that used `malloc` to get memory for the result and required the results to eventually be `free`d, you would probably get similar results.

So how might the C++ implementation be improved?

As mentioned, you could either `reserve` the vectors before adding data to them, or give them an initial size and do assignments like `v[i] = out;` rather than `push_back(out);`.

The next easiest step would be to use more operators that allow in-place calculations.  If you overloaded:

```
std::vector<double>& operator+=(const std::vector<double>&);
std::vector<double>& operator*=(double);
```

then you could do:

```
k += 0.0001*q;
n *= 2;
// or:
n += n;
```

to do the final computations on `k` and `n` in-place.  This doesn't easily help with the expression `0.0001*q`, though.

Another option that sometimes helps is to overload operators to accept rvalues in order to reuse storage that belonged to temporaries.  If we had an overload:

```
std::vector<double> operator+(const std::vector<double>& a, std::vector<double>&& b);
```

it would get called for the `+` in the expression `k + 0.0001*q`, and the implementation could create the return value from `std::move(b)`, reusing its storage.  This gets tricky to get both flexible and correct, though.  And it still doesn't eliminate the temporary representing `0.0001*q` or its allocation and deallocation.

Another solution that allows in-place calculations in the most general cases is called expression templates.  That's rather a lot of work to implement, but if you really need a combination of convenient syntax and efficiency, there are some existing libraries that might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I should have taken a closer look on how you perform the c-array operations... See aschepler's answer on why growing the vectors is the least of your problems.

–––

If you have any idea how many elements you are going to add to a `vector`, you should always call `reserve` on the vector before adding them. Otherwise you are going to trigger a potentially large amount of reallocations, which are costly.

A `vector` occupies a continuous block of memory. To grow, it has to allocate a larger block of memory and copy its entire content to the new location. To avoid this happening every time a element is added, the vector usually allocates more memory than is presently needed to store all its elements. The number of elements it can store without reallocation is its capacity. How large this capacity should be is of course a trade off between avoiding potential future reallocation and wasting memory. 
However, if you know (or have a good idea) how many elements will eventually be stored in the `vector`, you can call `reserve(n)` to set its capacity to (at least) `n` and avoid unecessary reallocation.

Edit :

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168051/why-push-back-is-slower-than-operator-for-an-previous-allocated-vector). `push_back` performes a bound check and is thus a bit slower than just writing to the `vector` through `operator[]`. In your case it might be fastest to directly construct a `vector` of size (not just capacity) `n`, as `doubles` are POD and cheap to construct, and than insert the correct values through `operator[]`.